# Simple Vue example not working only producing the brackets

Tags: html, vue.js

Can someone help me with this.

I have looked at other eksampels inkluding: [Simple Vue slot example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152598/simple-vue-slot-example-not-working)

and

[Vue not working in a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967075/vue-not-working-in-a-simple-example)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="dk">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="number in numbers">{{ number }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.33/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the main.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        numbers: [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
    },
});
```

I have tried in Valet and on live server

Comment: what is not working in this code ? It's working fine. sample jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fz94k37h/

Comment: No it's not working he used vue 3 and you used vue 2 thats why

Comment: Use Vue 3.x to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed vue 2 code with vue 3 that's why

if you want to use vue 3 you need to use Vue.createApp function

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            numbers: [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
        }
    })
app.mount('#app')
```

if you want to use vue 2 then you need to change your unpkg script src